# kali linux boots (cd and usb) into black screen with lines

Tags: linux, dual-boot, kali-linux, macintosh

I am trying to dual boot Kali Linux on my Mac desktop. When I try to run it live it runs through the start-up but boots into a bunch of colored lines down the screen then goes black. I can hear the cd still turning. I installed it with the same results.

I can't figure out why it's booting to a blank black screen. I have checked the downloads to make sure they have correct SHA checksums.

yes the boot screen looks the same as that just a blue background. The live (amd64 failsafe) boots then shows the kali logos crammed like 4 tiles across the top of the screen then goes to black. But when I go to manually shut it down cause its a black screen, it will come back on and go through a process. It says shutting down ok, _____ ok, just like when it boots up. So I am thinking that black screen is the log in screen. Is there something that could be making it just so my computer isn't displaying it correctly???
  I have tryed ububntu also with goes to a black screen after the purple one with keyboard. The only success I had was debian. But I need kali linux as all the programs are on there. Also debian's terminal is in a whole different window from all the programs.

Comment: Hello and welcome to U+L. Could you provide us with more details concerning your setup? What Mac model is it? Which version of Kali are you trying to run? Do you have any external displays connected?

Comment: it is a mac desktop 2009 running 10.10. and I tried both kali-linux amd64.iso and the 32 both give me the same result. I don't know what you mean by external displays? It will boot to the refind then I select the iso disk, which runs then I can choose live, live usb, install, when i choose live it runs through boot process. but where the login screen should be nothing colored lines then black.

Comment: Sorry about the external displays confusion. I somehow foolishly thought this was a MacBook and I though about the built-in display and external devices. Nevermind :)

Answer (score 0):

The boot menu should have failsafe mode in one of the options.
[image: screenshot]